# Android Action Bar and Menu Access

Tags: android

My app likes to have as much screen space as it can on phones, so I've been using the NoTitleBar theme up to now. Going forward for V3.0+, at least on tablets, I'd like to support the Action Bar since there's room for it and it has some nice features, so I might use one of the standard Holo themes in that case.

I don't care about providing Action Bar features for pre-3.0 devices, but I'm not sure that I want to have an Action Bar on smartphones at all due to the screen space that it takes up. My only concern is if Android devices made for Honeycomb and later will always have a menu button somewhere on the screen external to the app. I would assume that this button will always appear somewhere in the area of the Home and Back buttons -- is this correct?

One reason I'm asking is that I already had to make some changes due to the assumption that Android phones would always have a hard Search key -- remember that "requirement"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you configure things correctly, then you will not have an additional menu button on Honeycomb. This only happens in apps which declare an options menu without specifying the `android:showAsAction` attribute to determine how it should be displayed in the ActionBar. You can comfortably use this attribute, and it will be ignored by pre-Honeycomb devices. You will get an options menu on pre-Honeycomb, and proper integration in the ActionBar on Honeycomb and later.

More information on this can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html).